# LWRP Shaders not working in android! only working in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity game development. I making a mobile game. In LWRP I made a custom shader graph (glow shader). It works fine in unity in my pc. But when I build a .APK and install and play on my android device it shows a plain block with no shaders.

Am I missing something?

[image]

[image]

This my shader graph.
[image]

After clear inspection, I noticed most of the shader works. Only the occlusion part doesn't work properly. I have set occlusion to 5. Normally what occlusion does in my graph is kind off saturates the material a little and gives a deep reflective glow kinda effect to the shader. It works on PC. But on the phone, I noticed the color did get saturated a little but didn't notice the occlusion glow at all.

(I know I can produce nearly similar results without using occlusion, but I really felt occlusion suits more for my taste :P and I will be using occlusion for other objects too)

quality settings: 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of your graph?It looks to me like the difference is mainly in the specular reflections. Also make sure that your default quality in the quality settings is the same for android as it is for desktop.

Comment: @KalleHalvarsson Hi, I added a screenshot of the shader graph. In the quality settings, both are set to fastest. In graphic settings, I even tried using FP16 instead of the default R11G11B10 but I am getting the same occlusion less result.

Answer (score 0):

I think using opengl3 will fix that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for contributing an answer. This would be even better though, if you could [edit] it to explain why using OpenGL3 would fix the problem. See [answer].

Answer (score -1):

Check your Graphics API in player setting, it should be under Other Settings

Comment: Check your graphics API ... for what? Which setting should be checked and set to what value?